# Encoding error in GIF LZW compressed stream

Tags: c, encoding, sdl, gif, lzw

I'm writing a C library to export SDL_Surfaces to various formats as an exercise,
and so far, I got the BMP, TGA and PCX formats down. Now I'm working on the GIF
format and I feel I'm very close to getting it working. My implementation is a
modified version of [this one](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/LZW_compression#C).

My current problem is writing the GIF LZW compressed image data sub-blocks. Everything goes smooth until
position 208 in the first sub-block. The three bytes in the original file are (starting from position 207):
"B8 29 B2" in hexadecimal, and mine are "B8 41 B2". After that, the bytes "sync" up
again. Further down the compressed stream I can find similar differences, probably
caused by the first error. My file is also shorter than the original.

I should note that I changed the type of the lzw_entry struct from a uint16_t to int to allow
-1 as an "empty" entry since 0 is a valid entry. It didn't really make a difference
in the compressed stream though. The original implementation uses uninitialized data
to mark an empty entry instead.

I think I'm reading my dictionary values incorrectly which is why I get another code for position 208 than expected. Otherwise, my bitpacking is incorrect.

I've added a stripped-down version of my compression code. What might be the problem?  Also, how I can
make either my "dictionary" data structure better or make the bitstream writing faster?

Finally, I'm also aware that I can optimize some code here and there :)

```
static Uint8 bit_count = 0;
static Uint8 block_pos = 0;

int LZW_PackBits(SDL_RWops *dst, Uint8 *block, int code, Uint8 bits) {
    Uint8 out = 0;

    while (out != bits) {
        if (bit_count == 8) {
            bit_count = 0;

            if (block_pos == 254) { // Thus 254 * 8 + 8 == 2040 -> 2040 / 8 = 255 -> buffer full
                ++block_pos;
                SDL_RWwrite(dst, &block_pos, 1, 1);
                SDL_RWwrite(dst, &block[0], 1, block_pos);
                memset(block, 0, block_pos);
                block_pos = 0;
            } else
                ++block_pos;
        }

        block[block_pos] |= (code >> out & 0x1) << bit_count;
        ++bit_count; ++out;
    }

    return 1;
}

#define LZW_MAX_BITS      12
#define LZW_START_BITS    9
#define LZW_CLEAR_CODE    256
#define LZW_END_CODE      257
#define LZW_ALPHABET_SIZE 256

typedef struct {
    int next[LZW_ALPHABET_SIZE]; // int so that -1 is allowed
} lzw_entry;

int table_size       = 1 << LZW_MAX_BITS; // 2^12 = 4096
lzw_entry *lzw_table = (lzw_entry*)malloc(sizeof(lzw_entry) * table_size);

for (i = 0; i < table_size; ++i)
    memset(&lzw_table[i].next[0], -1, sizeof(int) * LZW_ALPHABET_SIZE);

Uint8 block[255];
memset(&block[0], 0, 255);
Uint16 next_entry = LZW_END_CODE + 1;
Uint8  out_len    = LZW_START_BITS;
Uint8  next_byte  = 0;
int    input      = 0;
int    nc         = 0;

LZW_PackBits(dst, block, clear_code, out_len);

Uint8 *pos = ... // Start of image data
Uint8 *end = ... // End of image data
input = *pos++;

while (pos < end) {
    next_byte = *pos++;
    nc = lzw_table[input].next[next_byte];

    if (nc >= 0) {
        input = nc;
        continue;
    } else {
        LZW_PackBits(dst, block, input, out_len);
        nc    = lzw_table[input].next[next_byte] = next_entry++;
        input = next_byte;
    }

    if (next_entry == (1 << out_len)) { // Next code requires more bits
        ++out_len;

        if (out_len > LZW_MAX_BITS) {
            // Reset table
            LZW_PackBits(dst, block, clear_code, out_len - 1);
            out_len = LZW_START_BITS;
            next_entry = LZW_END_CODE + 1;

            for (i = 0; i < table_size; ++i)
                memset(&lzw_table[i].next[0], -1, sizeof(int) * LZW_ALPHABET_SIZE);
        }
    }
}

// Write remaining stuff including current code (not shown)
LZW_PackBits(dst, block, end_code, out_len);
++block_pos;
SDL_RWwrite(dst, &block[0], 1, block_pos);
SDL_RWwrite(dst, &zero_byte, 1, 1);

const Uint8 trailer = 0x3b; // ';'
SDL_RWwrite(dst, &trailer, 1, 1);
```

**UPDATE:** I've done some more tests, and implemented the bit packing algorithm that Aki Suihkonen suggested. It made no noticable difference which tells me that I'm somehow looking up/storing codes incorrectly in my lzw_table structure and that the error(s) is in the main loop.

Answer (score 2):

It's not the cause of the problem, but is there a need to write character 255 every now and then?
`SDL_RWwrite(dst, &block_pos, 1, 1);`

First pointer how to make the bit-writing faster:

```
void bitpacker(int what, int howmany)
{
   static unsigned int bit_reservoir=0;
   static int bits_left = 0;
   static unsigned char *my_block = start_of_block;

   bit_reservoir|=what<<bits_left;   // you can optionally mask: (what & ((1<<howmany)-1))
   bits_left+=howmany;
   while (bits_left >= 8) {
       *myblock++ = bit_reservoir;
       bits_left-=8;
       bit_reservoir>>=8;            // EDIT: added, even though it's so obvious :)
       if (myblock==end_of_block) { my_block=start_of_block;  
           write(my_block,1,block_size, outputfile);
       }
   }
   // and while we are here, why not reserve a few kilobytes at least for myblock?

}
```

4MB memory for the dictionary is a lot (especially compared to year 1987, when the standard was developed), but probably not that much to justify writing a more complex hash table. The basic unit could be short though. You can also initialize it to zero, if you just write code+1 to the table (and read it as table[a].next[b] -1)..

The table clearing can be optimized. There are 4MB of memory reserved but less than 4k entries used.

```
 int *clear_table[MAX_CODES];
 ...
 {
     // memorize the address that is changed...
     int *tmp = clear_table[next_entry] = &lzw_table[input].next[next_byte];
     nc    = *tmp = next_entry++;
 }
 if (need_to_clear) { for (int i=258;i<MAX_CODE;i++) *(clear_table[i]) = 0;
```

Comment: Yes. The GIF version of LZW requires compressed data to be packed in sub-blocks. Each sub-block is a byte (1-255) telling you how many bytes are in the sub-block, then that many bytes of compressed data follow. Most blocks will thus contain a 255 block count except for probably the last one. Thanks for the bitpacker. I tried writing something similar, but somehow, I just couldn't wrap my head around it. I like the your idea of 'code+1' as well. I could make a hashtable, but I thought this idea was simple to start off with.

Comment: Right. Couldn't remember that. Seems so obsoleted at year 2012... How many codes one has to clear? ~3840 out of 1M. Why not store the addresses of the occupied slots to an array? (anyway, first priority is to get the code working...)

Comment: Well. Since the spec allows a max bit length of 12, you have to clear 4096 codes (although with this implementation it's more than just that). I think I need you to explain that a bit more, but yes, I agree: The code should work first and foremost :)

Comment: The codes 0..258 actually are reserved... So we can subtract 2.

Comment: Assuming 8bits/pixel (which this is), the clearcode and end-of-information code then yes, those are reserved. The clearcode is 2^8=256 and the EOI code is clearcode+1=257. The first free code is then 258 and is not reserved.